# Why is the question and the answer down voted in this case?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Super User post: [How to access from physical lan to wireless router?](https://superuser.com/questions/1237444/how-to-access-from-physical-lan-to-wireless-router)

If someone gives a working answer better than I found, then I can change it. Or maybe edit the post to met the correct ways. But I don't know which are those "correct ways". I'll be greatful if someone can take the time to explain this, so I follow the best practices of the site (which it seems I didn't).

Comment: The question appears poorly researched and I have a feeling that is probably a duplicate. I can't find the duplicates at this time though.

Comment: "Poorly researched"?? Seriously? I tried to add every single piece of information I could get... plus when no one even TRY to understand what I wrote and no one even try an answer either... I answer my own question by (guess what) researching. Please, make an effort to TRY at least a serious explanation.

Comment: I think the question is okay, but your answer is not very clear. I'm not sure that someone with the same question as you would find the answer helpful. I suggest editing it to include more explanation of what the problem was and how your solution addresses that problem.

Comment: I will take your suggestion @Blackwood. I'm editing the answer to try to clarify what I did to achieve the goal of the question. Thanks for your words!

Comment: @Ramhound And that's exactly what I'm doing here, that's the reason I made this question, to try to make it better. Sadly for me, write in another language (being it supposedly the most used in the world) that I used to write in my country, is very difficult. Sorry for the mistakes (did them worth downvotes?) I'm doing here my major effort to be clear. I'm rewriten the answer...

Comment: I don't really know what mistakes are you talking about, I double check everything I wrote, if I made mistakes is because I don't know enough english. Give me a hint about what to correct and I try my best. And, sincerely, tell "poorly researched" without reason and acussing me of not searching for duplicates not finding for him-herself... is not really serious, or it is?

Comment: Well @Ramhound I'm trying my best here. Short and concise. Hope it is fixed now. It will be a google translator problem then, I guess: https://goo.gl/x3fpNN

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but (1) I remember being bothered when I read “My PC is connected to DrayTek router with cable.” and then saw on the diagram that the PC was connected to a switch (which isn’t mentioned in the question at all), which was connected to the DrayTek router.  (2) Your diagram doesn’t show (2a) that the DrayTek router is connected to the Internet, (2b) any of the IP addresses, or (2c) the fact that the PC communicates with the D-Link wirelessly.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Regarding research: you don’t say how you tried to access the D-Link’s setup page, how it failed, and what you did to try to diagnose that failure.  (For example, could you ping it?  What error message did you get when you tried to browse to it?  Did you try to connect to it with ``telnet`` or ``nc``?  Did you try sniffing the network?)

Comment: You did an amazing job! it is more clear. I just correct some of your asumptions (which seems to be reasonable wrong due my poor english). Then some comments: I didn't say something about the switch because I think it wasn't nothing to do with the problem... then I add the picture to try to clarify and it seems to me fairy to add it if it is there, but just to make it clear. I'm not too good making lot of things (diagrams is one) so I forgot of adding some things that will cost me to do and I talked about on the post already.

Comment: The only way I try to enter to setup is by browser, entering to its IP. But I tried this way after trying modifing some configurations without any success (I was pretty sure that will not work at all but tried anyways). Until I discover the option I mention in the answer... so that way I can enter to router's setup from PC wired. And most important of all, without touching the way it gives internet to the other devices.